# Существуют ли языки программирования, в которых есть оператор `min=`?

Tags: любой-язык, перегрузка-операторов, операторы, оператор-присваивания

Например, в C++ есть оператор `+=`:

```
x += 7;
```

который является сокращённой записью оператора `+` с последующим присваиванием:

```
x = x + 7;
```

---

Существует ли язык программирования, в котором есть оператор `min=` или `=min`:

```
x =min 7
```

который бы являлся сокращённой записью взятия минимума с последующим присваиванием:

```
x = min(x, 7)
```

?

Comment: Думаю то, что Вам нужно (`gcc` ранней версии):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199630/what-does-the-operator-mean

Comment: ...но зачем? [картинка с троллейбусом]

Comment: @AresGod прикольно, жаль что его убрали

Comment: @andreymal, например может пригодится в конструкциях `very_big_variable_name = min(very_big_variable_name, 7)` или `array[index1][index2] = min(array[index1][index2], 7)` или `somevariable.somemethod_returns_lvalue() = min(somevariable.somemethod_returns_lvalue(), 7)`

Comment: Думается, для такого будет лучше просто сокращающий макрос написать)

Comment: @user268670 никто не мешает использовать вам старую версию компилятора) но я бы ради такого сахара не стал бы мучаться так:)

Comment: Я думаю что тут ничего нет если строчка будет чуточку длиннее)

Comment: Синтаксический сахар используют как правило лишь для регулярных базовых операций. Применение математических функций никому не нужно в виде сахара. Такой сахар только усложнит читаемость кода. Я не знаю, может разве что в каком-то специализированном языке для математиков такое уместно.